# Visual Studio setting of getch()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, getch

Why ch=_getch() reads a space after every character which it can't be ignored with "if (ch!=' ')" ? This isn't happening in CodeBlocks ,only in newest Visual 15.7.1. How to set Visual Studio to get rid of that space? I'm using 64-bit windows 10

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx. _getch() returns int. What is the return value you get?

Comment: It doesn't. You're probably misinterpreting your results, possibly trying to interpret a Unicode string as something else. Show your [MCVE], as always a requirement here.

Comment: I resolved that with an if that takes only letters and numbers,that character wasn't a space,it was "NULL" pointer and my password application hadn't work property with it